# Vagrant syncing to the wrong default folder on Windows?

Tags: windows, shared-folders, vagrant, mobaxterm

I don't have any "sync" configuration in my Vagrantfile at all, and yet the folder that is syncing to `/vagrant` is not the project directory, but my home directory.

This is on a Windows computer working via MobaXterm.

With slight editing for privacy, the paths involved look like:

```
$ pwd
/home/mobaxterm/vagrant_files/my_project
$ echo ~
/home/mobaxterm
$ vagrant up
...
==> host001: Mounting shared folders...
    host001: /vagrant => C:/Users/myname
...
```

If I go through Windows Explorer, the path corresponding to `/home/mobaxterm` (i.e. `~`) is:

```
C:\Users\myname\Documents\MobaXterm\home
```

How can I make Vagrant sync `C:/Users/myname/Documents/MobaXterm/home/vagrant_files/my_project` to `/vagrant` rather than syncing `C:/Users/myname`?

Also, is there a documented bug in either Vagrant or MobaXterm that is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most elegant fix, but have you tried modifying the Vagrantfile?

```
vm.synced_folder "C:/Users/myname/Documents/MobaXterm/home/vagrant_files/my_project" "/vagrant"
```